# Table as 'option list' under IOS5

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios5, cell

I make some UI under IOS5 that enables to select 1 item from some 5 items.

As a beginner in this platform I am looking for the best solution. First I thought to create a list view which's items can be checked. I could make it, but idi not find a solution 'out of the box' that checks one item by clicking and uncheck all others. Is it the normal way to implement it by code? Or does listview have some kind of 'check-the-clicked-cell-and-uncheck-others' property/method?

I know I can use also picker view as an option selector but I prefer checkable table this time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box uITableView solution. You would have to handle unchecking the other table view cells programmatically by adding some code to tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I could implement it, I asked to be sure there is no built in support for this problem. It surprises me a little there is not.